# Regular expression for finding the last occurrence of a string within a string

Tags: regex

I use regular expression for parsing some records, and I have difficulty figuring out how to construct the regular expression for finding the below scenario.

example record:
this is a test string 425=UA113456 jkjkj 425=**AB1234X** this is a test string 795=12 this is a test string.

Requirements. find tag 795=12 and search back to find the value for tag 425. In this case the return value should be AB1235X. 
Note: there could be multiple 425= tags like in this example there are two of them but I need the value for the tag which is right before 795=12.

This is what I have so far   ^.* 425=(.*?) 795=12    but not exactly what I need.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I tried all the suggested solutions but they didn't work.

Comment: I'm pasting the actual string with the actual tags. In case in will help finding the solution..

Comment: 8=FIX.4.4 9=1234 35=8 49=MA 56=CATSTFF 34=50 52=20170818-20:26:06.772 453=5 448=captest1uk 447=C 452=11 448=Caup Research, Inc. & its Affiliates 447=D 452=13 448=dlr3ukma1 447=D 452=12 448=BEARGB21XXX 447=B 452=1 448=DLR3LEI123451234 447=N 452=1 761=4 699=DE0001141729 662=101.899 663=1 218=-414.300 6707=-0.348

Comment: the tag which I'm looking for is   447=N 452=1  and the value that I'm expecting to return is DLR3LEI123451234, that belongs to last 448=  that comes before my target tag.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all tags are digits, Use this Pattern `(\d+)=(\S+)[^=]*795=12` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6t5Oq5/6) or [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6t5Oq5/7)

```
(           # Capturing Group (1)
  \d        # <digit 0-9>
  +         # (one or more)(greedy)
)           # End of Capturing Group (1)
=           # "="
(           # Capturing Group (2)
  \S        # <not a whitespace character>
  +         # (one or more)(greedy)
)           # End of Capturing Group (2)
[^=]        # Character not in [=] Character Class
*           # (zero or more)(greedy)
795=12      # "795=12"
```

or based on what you tried, use this `425=(\S+)[^=]*795=12`

Comment: Thank you for your time but it didn't return the value I was expecting

Comment: @HarveyA., `AB1235X` is returned in group #2 per the Demo Link ??

Answer (score 0):

This works, though it assumes support for lookaround assertions:

```
(?<=425=)\b(\w+)\b(?=[a-zA-Z\s]*795=12)
```

- \b(\w+)\b              match the word
- (?<=425=)              preceded by 425=
- (?=[a-zA-Z\s]*795=12)  followed by characters and spaces, followed by 795=12

Comment: Thank you for your time but it didn't return the value I was expecting

Comment: What did it return, and what value were you expecting?

Comment: I got an error that says an attempt to repeat something that can not be repeated. for example a*+ .  BTW I'm using Alteryx and its regEx tool for this.